# Assigning a custom field whenever a post is created

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I'm trying to add a custom field to all of my posts containing the post summary. I have created a custom field called "post-summary". What I want to do is to assign a value to this custom field automatically.

```
<?php 
$value = somefunction($content);
add_post_meta( {{current post id}} , 'post-summary', $value , true ) || update_post_meta( {{current post id}} , 'post-summary', $value );
```

How to apply this whenever a new post is published?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post) hook which is basically [save_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) that only fires when a post is first created. And update_post_meta will actually add the custom field value, you don't need to do add_post_meta first.

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'set_your_default_summary' );

function set_your_default_summary( $post_id ) {
  // Check to make sure this post is for the right post type
  if( 'your_post_type' == get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {

      $post = get_post($post_id);

      $value = somefunction($post->post_content);

            // Make sure this isn't just a revision auto-saving
        if( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_summary', $value );
        }

       return $post_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting. I copied and pasted that right out of my functions.php file where it is currently working.

Comment: It does not show any errors because I'm using MAMP to develop locally but it returns a fatal error because everything stops working!

Comment: I assume you're replacing all the appropriate values from my sample (i.e. "your_post_type" with the name of the post type, somefunction() with your function's name).